# Multiple extract with BeautifulSoup doesn't work

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here is an example of a piece of html I would like to clean:

```
<figure class="floatRight" style="margin-left: 30px">
<a class="zoomFunction alignLeft" href="https://www.thieme-connect.de/media/synthesis/EFirst/lookinside/ss-2015-c0259-st_10-1055_s-0034-1378861-1.jpg"><img src="https://www.thieme-connect.de/media/synthesis/EFirst/lookinside/thumbnails/ss-2015-c0259-st_10-1055_s-0034-1378861-1.jpg"/></a>
<figcaption></figcaption>
</figure>
<p>
<a name="N65743"></a>
</p><h3>Abstract</h3>
<p>2-<span class="i">tert</span>-Butyl-5-iodoindolizine underwent Sonogashira reaction with acetylenes in the presence of dichlorobis(triphenylphosphine)palladium, copper(I) iodide, and triethylamine in acetonitrile to give to the corresponding 5-ethynylindolizines in high yields; 5-iodo-2-phenylindolizine and 5-bromo-2-<span class="i">tert</span>-butylindolizine did not undergo the reaction. Several structures were characterized by X-ray. The 5-ethynylindolizines did not undergo cyclization to give cycl[3.2.2]azines.</p>
<div class="articleKeywords">
<a name="N65760"></a>
<h3>Key words</h3>
5-iodoindolizines - 
        Sonogashira reaction - 
        5-ethynylindolizine - 
        X-ray
      </div>
<a name="N67312"></a>
<h3>Supporting Information</h3>
<ul class="linkList">Supporting information for this article is available online at http://dx.doi.org/10.1055/s-0034-1378861.<li>
<a class="gotolink" href="https://www.thieme-connect.de/media/synthesis/EFirst/supmat/sup_ss-2015-c0259-st_10-1055_s-0034-1378861.pdf">Supporting Information</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

What I would basically do is something like that:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with open("test.xml", 'r') as file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(file.read(), "lxml")

abstract = soup

[tag.extract() for tag in abstract("a", attrs={"name": True})]
[tag.extract() for tag in abstract("h3")]
[tag.extract() for tag in abstract("ul", attrs={"class": "linkList"})]
[tag.extract() for tag in abstract("a", attrs={"class": "gotolink"})]

print(abstract)
```

I expect the multiple extract() lines to clean each matching tag. However, only the first one works ! I can get rid of the "a" tags, but not the "h3" tags. If I comment the first extract line (the one for the "a" tags), I can get rid of the "h3" tags, but not the others.

It's a bit weird. Do you know why I get this behavior ?

I use BeautifulSoup4 4.4.0 freshly installed from pip

Comment: Why do you use list-comprehensions instead of regular for-loops `for tag in ...: tag.extract()`?

Comment: I can't reproduce the described behaviour in an interpreter with the given piece of HTML.  Every tags are removed according to the filtering rules.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to create a new Beautiful Soup object after each extract, and execute the next extract on this new object.

This might look a bit ugly, but it works:

**clean.py**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with open("test.xml", 'r') as file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(file.read(), "lxml")

abstract = soup

[tag.extract() for tag in abstract("a", attrs={"name": True})]
abstract = BeautifulSoup(str(abstract))
[tag.extract() for tag in abstract("h3")]
abstract = BeautifulSoup(str(abstract))
[tag.extract() for tag in abstract("ul", attrs={"class": "linkList"})]
abstract = BeautifulSoup(str(abstract))
[tag.extract() for tag in abstract("a", attrs={"class": "gotolink"})]

print(abstract)
```

**The output**

*BEFORE CLEANING*

```
(bs4extract)macbook:bs4extract joeyoung$ cat test.xml 
<figure class="floatRight" style="margin-left: 30px">
<a class="zoomFunction alignLeft" href="https://www.thieme-connect.de/media/synthesis/EFirst/lookinside/ss-2015-c0259-st_10-1055_s-0034-1378861-1.jpg"><img src="https://www.thieme-connect.de/media/synthesis/EFirst/lookinside/thumbnails/ss-2015-c0259-st_10-1055_s-0034-1378861-1.jpg"/></a>
<figcaption></figcaption>
</figure>
<p>
<a name="N65743"></a>
</p><h3>Abstract</h3>
<p>2-<span class="i">tert</span>-Butyl-5-iodoindolizine underwent Sonogashira reaction with acetylenes in the presence of dichlorobis(triphenylphosphine)palladium, copper(I) iodide, and triethylamine in acetonitrile to give to the corresponding 5-ethynylindolizines in high yields; 5-iodo-2-phenylindolizine and 5-bromo-2-<span class="i">tert</span>-butylindolizine did not undergo the reaction. Several structures were characterized by X-ray. The 5-ethynylindolizines did not undergo cyclization to give cycl[3.2.2]azines.</p>
<div class="articleKeywords">
<a name="N65760"></a>
<h3>Key words</h3>
5-iodoindolizines - 
        Sonogashira reaction - 
        5-ethynylindolizine - 
        X-ray
      </div>
<a name="N67312"></a>
<h3>Supporting Information</h3>
<ul class="linkList">Supporting information for this article is available online at http://dx.doi.org/10.1055/s-0034-1378861.<li>
<a class="gotolink" href="https://www.thieme-connect.de/media/synthesis/EFirst/supmat/sup_ss-2015-c0259-st_10-1055_s-0034-1378861.pdf">Supporting Information</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

*AFTER CLEANING*

```
(bs4extract)macbook:bs4extract joeyoung$ python clean.py 
<html><body><figure class="floatRight" style="margin-left: 30px">
<a class="zoomFunction alignLeft" href="https://www.thieme-connect.de/media/synthesis/EFirst/lookinside/ss-2015-c0259-st_10-1055_s-0034-1378861-1.jpg"><img src="https://www.thieme-connect.de/media/synthesis/EFirst/lookinside/thumbnails/ss-2015-c0259-st_10-1055_s-0034-1378861-1.jpg"/></a>
<figcaption></figcaption>
</figure>
<p>
</p>
<p>2-<span class="i">tert</span>-Butyl-5-iodoindolizine underwent Sonogashira reaction with acetylenes in the presence of dichlorobis(triphenylphosphine)palladium, copper(I) iodide, and triethylamine in acetonitrile to give to the corresponding 5-ethynylindolizines in high yields; 5-iodo-2-phenylindolizine and 5-bromo-2-<span class="i">tert</span>-butylindolizine did not undergo the reaction. Several structures were characterized by X-ray. The 5-ethynylindolizines did not undergo cyclization to give cycl[3.2.2]azines.</p>
<div class="articleKeywords">

5-iodoindolizines - 
        Sonogashira reaction - 
        5-ethynylindolizine - 
        X-ray
      </div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok sorry guys, the bug comes from BeautifulSoup actually. The exact same code works perfectly when downgrading to 4.3.2-3. I'll report it. Sorry I didn't check that before posting.